# Missing GPSTimeStamp , GPSDateStamp when select image from gallery iOS 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, metadata

When select image from gallery iPhone version 13.1.2 , i see meta data GPS location missing GPSTimeStamp , GPSDateStamp .
How can I interpret this? Thank you !

```
 ALAssetRepresentation* representation = [info 
 defaultRepresentation];
 NSDictionary *metadata = representation.metadata;
 LogInfo(@"****metadata = %@ *****",metadata)
 =>This is log result :
 "{GPS}" =     {
    Altitude = "6.885073656845754";
    AltitudeRef = 0;
    DestBearing = "20.69101142995269";
    DestBearingRef = T;
    HPositioningError = 10;
    ImgDirection = "20.69101142995269";
    ImgDirectionRef = T;
    Latitude = "10.32532833333333";
    LatitudeRef = N;
    Longitude = "106.4042966666667";
    LongitudeRef = E;
    Speed = 0;
    SpeedRef = K;
};
```

Comment: The asset library (ALAsset and related classes) is deprecated as of iOS 9.0. Maybe something has been removed finally - although I haven't found anything in the release notes about it. Nevertheless, it may be good advice to move on to PhotoKit.

Comment: I don't know what has changed with iOS 13.1.2, even if I try to add a location to the metadata it was still lost GPSTimeStamp , GPSDateStamp when I reviewed the images